# Set PAGE_GUARD protection to large page

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm working on Windows 7 , 64bit application.

After successful large page allocation, I'm trying to set PAGE_GUARD protection flag to the first large page using VirtualProtect.
This is a code I'm using:

```
unsigned long long memSize = 1024*1024*1024;
char* data = (char*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, memSize, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT|MEM_LARGE_PAGES, PAGE_READWRITE);

//make the first large page in the allocated buffer be a guard page
DWORD oldProtect;
SIZE_T pageSize = GetLargePageMinimum();
LPVOID startPtr = data;
bool res = VirtualProtect(startPtr, pageSize, PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_GUARD, &oldProtect);
```

Permanently I get the following error:
GetLastError() returns error 487 - "Attempt to access invalid address."

Everything is working fine while allocating and setting PAGE_GUARD protection for regular pages (4KB).

Is guard protection supported for large pages? If so, what's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Guard protection is not supported for large pages.  It isn't explicitly documented, but it can be inferred.  To quote from [MSDN Large-Page Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The memory is always read/write and nonpageable (always resident in physical memory).

`PAGE_GUARD` works by setting PAGE_NOACCESS internally, and then resetting the page to the desired protection level after the page is read or written (as NOACCESS it will raise an exception that Windows handles internally).  Since large pages ***must*** be read/write, the system is unable to implement the guard behavior as requested.

To be honest, I'm not sure if this is a limitation imposed by Windows itself or due a legacy limitation of our underlying x86 hardware.  I *think* if it was a hardware limitation, that it may have been a limitation on earlier x86/32 architectures.  I'm positive that it no longer applies to any modern x64 architectures.  (newer Linux kernels, for example, can use large pages transparently without the programming having to make explicit requests)